# Вставка значения из атрибута в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть атрибут `data-lesson` и есть пару занятий с этим же атрибутом, но ( как очевидно ) с разными значениями. При нажатии на кнопку должно браться значение атрибута `data-lesson` и вставляться в `input`. Сделал примерно рабочий код, но при нажатии на другое занятие не меняется значение ( `value` ) в  `input` 
Вот код

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.openAlert').click(function() {
          $('.form').addClass('active');
          var hey = $('.openAlert').attr('data-lesson');
          $('#curs_little').attr('value', hey)
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-xl openAlert" data-lesson="Мероприятие">
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-label white-btn-label">Записаться</span>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-xl openAlert" data-lesson="Подарочные сертификаты">
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-label white-btn-label">Записаться</span>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-xl openAlert" data-lesson="Детские развивающие группы">
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-paint"></span>
    <span class="btn-label white-btn-label">Записаться</span>
</a>
<!-- Сам input -->
<div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Курс" required data-validation-required-message="Выберите курс!" name="curs_little" id="curs_little"/>
</div>
```

Comment: В строке `var hey = $('.openAlert').attr('data-lesson');` замените `$('.openAlert')` на `$(this)`

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, решил  проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке `var hey = $('.openAlert').attr('data-lesson');` замените `$('.openAlert')` на `$(this)`